# How can I use awk to get value multiple times from one file to other file?

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk

File1:

```
01 999 234 432 666 
02 888 453 234 763
03 145 334 235 456
04 234 784 482 785
05 868 453 546 787
```

File2:

```
01
01
02
03
03
05
```

As I want to do matching between the first column of the 2 files and get the expected output as shown:

Expected Output:

```
999 234 432 666
999 234 432 666
888 453 234 763
145 334 235 456
145 334 235 456
868 453 546 787
```

And I tried the code below:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1; next} {if($1 in a) {print $2" "$3" "$4" "$5}}' file2 file1
```

however what I got is like that:

```
999 234 432 666
888 453 234 763
145 334 235 456
868 453 546 787
```

So How can I get the expected output by using awk?

Comment: Do you really have your heart set on awk? The `join` command at least can do this (perhaps with a bit of post-processing to remove the join field). Possibly datamash could do to, but I haven't tested that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build the lookup table from the first file, then index into it from the second - e.g.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1] = $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5; next} {print a[$1]}' file1 file2
999 234 432 666
999 234 432 666
888 453 234 763
145 334 235 456
145 334 235 456
868 453 546 787
```

Alternatively,

```
join -o1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5 file1 file2
```